# Flutter windowmanager working in the previous flutter. It stopped working and keep saying it is using deprecated api since I upgraded to null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages

I've created a method like this.

```
import 'package:flutter_windowmanager/flutter_windowmanager.dart';

Future<void> disableCapture() async {
  await FlutterWindowManager.addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
}
```

I called that method wherever in the **initstate** of the screen I want to prevent screenshot or screen record.
It works in previous flutter without sound null safety. However it **stopped working** when I upgraded the flutter to **sound null safety.**
It keeps saying it is using a deprecated api.
How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Update your package to null-safety version of flutter_windowmanager. If still it doesn't work, you have to wait for the package's updated version.

Comment: Yeah I've updated it to 0.2.0 latest for now. The problem is it sometimes works also. x')